# Calculating percentage between consecutive rows based on an ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate and find the largest percentage changes between dates based on an `indicator_id`

```
year                             indicator_id                 value
--------------------------      ---------------              -------
January 1, 1999, 12:00 AM             1                       1.99
January 1, 2000, 12:00 AM             1                       1.76
January 1, 2001, 12:00 AM             2                       3.37
January 1, 2006, 12:00 AM             2                       4.59
```

The output I'm trying to get is

```
year                             indicator_id                 value          % change
--------------------------      ---------------              -------         ---------
January 1, 1999, 12:00 AM             1                       1.99               0%
January 1, 2000, 12:00 AM             1                       1.76               ?
January 1, 2001, 12:00 AM             2                       3.37               0%
January 1, 2006, 12:00 AM             2                       4.59               ?
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You want `lag()` and some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (1 - value / nullif(lag(value) over (partition by indicator_id order by year), 0))  as ratio
from t;
```

Note:  This returns a ratio between 0 and 1.  You can multiple by 100, if you want a percentage.

Also, the first result is `NULL`, which makes more sense to me than `0`.  If you really want `0`, you can use the 3 argument form of `lag()`:  `lag(value, 1, value)`.

Comment: I get an error for division by zero. how can I fix this?

Comment: @a.r.  . . . Use `nullif()`.